# Resolution Changed -> Unity Launcher now in wrong location

Tags: unity, launcher

My old tft broke down. I have two actually. I had to replace the main one (originally I had 1980x1200 resolution) with one with 1980x1080. I fixed the resolution in the xorg.conf with the nvidia settings tool.

However unity/gnome doesn't seem to notice the resolution has changed?

Now my unity sidebar is only partially visible on the screen. How can I move it so it is fully visible again? I have not found any settings for that?

Update: Also on the login screen, the bar that would allow me to choose a non-unity classic session is not visible.

Comment: I am pretty sure as the resolution X is running is correct. I fixed that. also see my comment below. but thanks for asking I tried to clarify my post.

Comment: Did you just replace one monitor with another? Have you tried the Monitors utility in System Settings to detect your monitor? If you are using a proprietary driver, like me, you may need to run the settings utility for that driver. In my case it is the NVIDIA X server Settings. It has a feature called X Server Display Configuration with a button to Detect Displays and another to Save to X Configuration file. This is what I would use if I was replacing one monitor with another. There may be a similar utility for your video display driver. Regards.

Comment: thanks for tryin to help. i have already run the nividia server settings and it has - after x-restart - recognized the monitor and the changed resolution. I also checked the xorg.conf that the resolution was correctly updated. X is correct. I am having trouble with unity -.-

Comment: yes very definitely. the monitor packaging says 1980x1080 and the nvidia settings tool and xorg.conf say the same. Another weird symptom I am experiencing is that the image of the screen is kind of fuzzy or blurred just as if the resolution really was wrong -.-

Comment: I made one and magically everything is there. I think I am an idiot. I am trying to figure out how to calibrate that monitor. Still the sharpness is another issue I'll have to figure out

Comment: i found it would you mind posting a "real" answer so I can give you credit for it? thanks so very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks - have moved my comments into an answer (also tidied up by deleting my comments as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a hardware issue - but some preliminary checks should be made:

1. Double check the maximum resolution of the monitor via the box it came in/manual
2. Check if using Nvidia graphics that both nvidia-settings and `/etc/xorg.conf` resolutions agree with the resolution you were expecting.
3. Any other graphics cards, have a look at the "Monitor" window - both the monitor should be recognised and the correct resolution displayed.
4. Double check cabling from the PC to the monitor - could be loose/faulty

Once you are satisfied with these checks - have a look at the Monitor itself.

Most monitors have a button(s) that you can change the position of the screen vertically and horizontally as well as the width and height.

For sharpness issues - look for a setting that says "Auto" or "Fine".

Comment: Thanks :D it turned out that I forgot to check the monitor calibration. I found it when you suggested making a screenshot. Since the screenshot was perfect it could only be the monitor.